# docker: Connection refused on bound port from other device in the same NAT

Tags: docker, networking, raspbian

I'm trying to set up an HTTP server in a Docker container on port 8888 on a Raspbian host. I use `-p 8888:8888` to bind the port to all interfaces. This allows me to connect to it with `localhost:8888` without issue. However, when I connect to the bound port on the host from another device in the same NAT using its IP address (192.168.1.xxx), my connection is refused.

I'm using the bridge networking mode for this. I tried the "host" mode and that didn't work at all.

Comment: can you share the output of `netstat -ntpl |grep 8888`

Comment: @MaozZadok `tcp6       0      0 :::8888                 :::*                    LISTEN`

Comment: it looks good to me, I'd check for firewall, or networking issues, also make sure you can connect from the same device to the ipv4 internal address 192.168.1.xxx:8080

Comment: @MaozZadok I run other services on the same host without Docker and I can connect to them without issue using the ipv4 NAT address. Connecting to the server on the host using its own IP does work. I have not modified any firewall rules. I checked the iptables and there are some entries created by Docker, some of which make reference to port 8888 but I have no clue what they do.

Comment: If I run the server outside of the container then I can connect to it just fine on port 8888.

Comment: I ran into the same issue and I'm struggling to find a solution. Have you found it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to link the containers with the (deprecated) `—-link` command [documented here](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/). Otherwise they run in isolated networks. You can also use the more modern and supported way and create a network that each shares; both are described in the linked page.